# tcpClient Connecting Remote host freezes application

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, rfid

I'm quite new working with sockets and I'm trying to get data from a RFID equipment that has a raw streaming on port 1000. Found this code and I got this working on a console application with this code

```
   TcpClient tcpClient;
   NetworkStream networkStream;
   tcpClient = new TcpClient("10.19.1.101", 10000);
   networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
   StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
   StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
   String wline  = "";
   while (wline != "exit")
   {
       Console.Write(streamReader.ReadLine());
       Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
       Console.Write("next command:");
       wline = Console.ReadLine();
       streamWriter.Write(wline);
   }
```

Obviously this code waits for some commands to be written in the remote host but I don't need to write anything. I'm just trying to get the information sent by the RFID equipment that is basically a RFID tag code. Tag codes can arrive in random periods of time. I actually commented some lines in the previous code an was able to print the tag codes as arrive in the console.

```
TcpClient tcpClient;
NetworkStream networkStream;
tcpClient = new TcpClient("10.19.1.101", 10000);
networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
//StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
String wline  = "";
while (wline != "exit")
{
    Console.Write(streamReader.ReadLine());
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    //Console.Write("next command:");
    //wline = Console.ReadLine();
    //streamWriter.Write(wline);
}
```

I thing is not the correct way cause I'm not controlling the while loop. Can anybody guide me to the right path or approach to solve my "problem".

EDIT: I have changed the code and looks like this:

```
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("10.19.1.101", 10000);
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

        while (tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadLine();
        }
```

the curious thing is, when I do the same thing in a winFrom application the application freezes after a few times in the loop.

Comment: It sounds like your application is sufficiently simple that use of NetworkStream and TcpClient are providing too much functionality. It would be better to "keep it simple". Try to search for some examples of C# code that uses the Socket class directly, and reads input using Socket.Receive().

Comment: Did you check incoming connection??? May be client app didn't send any data into stream?

Comment: I made some testing in the winForm app where I have a datagridview for the data and It seems that the application is getting the data but is not added to the datagridview. When I use a counter for the loop an control the execution for a given number after that the all the information is added correctly at the same time to the datagridview. So I guess my problem is the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not updating the wline to the stream values inside the loop.